# Join two numpy arrays of unequal size and fill third array based on common column

Tags: python, arrays, join, numpy

I have two arrays of unequal size and dimensions:

```
a = [['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0', '0']
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1']
['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2']
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']]

b = [['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0']
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0']
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0']
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0']
['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0']
['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0']
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0']
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0']
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0']]
```

`b` contains multiple occurrences of `a`'s first column value. This is the join between the arrays.

In the desired output array wherever the `a`'s first column matches `b`'s
first column I want to add `a`'s second column such that:

```
 c = [['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0', '0']
 ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1']
 ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1']
 ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1']
 ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2']
 ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2']
 ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']
 ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']
 ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']]
```

`a` and `b` are in the low millions of lines and Python For loops to accomplish this are way too slow. So I am hoping I can accomplish this much more efficiently using Numpy methods.

Comment: To what degree does order matter? Can these be sorted by the first column?

Comment: Order in b does matter as these will be parsed as triangle triplets in building a mesh

Comment: The following solution worked very fast for my case:

>>> sorted_a = a[a.argsort(axis=0)[:,0]]
>>> insertion_points = numpy.searchsorted(sorted_a[:,0], b).ravel()
>>> sorted_a[insertion_points]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0', '0'],
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2'],
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']]

b = [['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0'],
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0'],
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0'],
['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0'],
['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0'],
['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0'],
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0'],
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0'],
['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0']]

df_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b)

print(df_a.merge(df_b))
```

Output

```
                               0  1
0  50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0  0
1  50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0  1
2  50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0  1
3  50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0  1
4  50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0  2
5  50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0  2
6  50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0  5
7  50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0  5
8  50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether this works for your specific case depends on some details, but it works for the simple example you've given.

```
>>> sorted_a = a[a.argsort(axis=0)[:,0]]
>>> insertion_points = numpy.searchsorted(sorted_a[:,0], b).ravel()
>>> sorted_a[insertion_points]
array([['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0', '0'],
       ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
       ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
       ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
       ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2'],
       ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2'],
       ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5'],
       ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5'],
       ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']], 
      dtype='<S29')
```

This begins by sorting `a`. Then it uses `searchsorted` to do a binary search in `a` for the correct insertion index for each value in `b`. Assuming the values in the first columns are all perfectly equal, the insertion indices returned have two nice properties. First, they point to the matching value in `a`. Second, they can be used as indices *into* `a` to create a new array using fancy indexing.

This makes creating the third array very easy. However, it draws *all* its data from `a`, not from `b`. If the values in `a` and `b` are not always equal, then the solution will have to be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0', '0'],
     ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
     ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2'],
     ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']]

b = [['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0'],
     ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0'],
     ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0'],
     ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0'],
     ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0'],
     ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0'],
     ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0'],
     ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0'],
     ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0']]

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
```

Find out where they match.

```
x = b == a[:,0]

>>> x
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Get the indices of the matches.

```
v = np.where(x)[1]

>>> v
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Use the indices to create the result from `a`

```
s = a[v]

>>> s
array([['50.561872473 25.047160868 0.0', '0'],
       ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
       ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
       ['50.561905852 25.047537575 0.0', '1'],
       ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2'],
       ['50.562232967 25.048109789 0.0', '2'],
       ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5'],
       ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5'],
       ['50.561940185 25.047914282 1.0', '5']], 
      dtype='|S29')
```

If there are duplicates in `a` this might not produce what you want.